# Convert Array to Hash in ruby with following structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a following array which displays information of users and some values related to the user. Following array contains information of two users Akiyo Riggs and Bingo

```
a1 = [["Akiyo Riggs", -32, "OverTime Hours", "",12],["Akiyo Riggs", -32, 
"Regular Hours", "", 18],["Bingo",-12,"OverTime Hours","",14], ["Bingo",
-12,"Regular Hours","",32]]
```

How can i convert into following array of hashes in which key is the user name and value is a hash with respective values

```
[{"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12], "Regular Hours"=>["", 18]},
{"Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14], "Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}]
```

Comment: You can do it in many ways. But what have you tried already ? Can u show us the code so we could help in fixing it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a1.map { |x,_,p,*ps| {x => {p => ps} } }.reduce({}, :deep_merge)
# => {"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12], "Regular Hours"=>["", 18]},
#     "Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14], "Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}}
```

Note: if efficiency is concerned, consider using `deep_merge!` instead of `deep_merge`, so that `reduce` wouldn't create a new hash on every iteration.

Some explanation:

```
a1.map { |x,_,p,*ps| {x => {p => ps} } }
```

gives us an array of hashes like this

```
 [{"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12]}},
  {"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"Regular Hours"=>["", 18]}},
  {"Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14]}},
  {"Bingo"=>{"Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}}]
```

which we can recursively merge with ActiveSupport [Hash#deep_merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge)

Comment: Author asked for Array, but you return hash.

Comment: The hash form is arguably more useful.

Comment: @MarkThomas of course, but that's still not an answer to author's question. btw this variant is 2 times slower that others.

Comment: Well I still think it qualifies as a good answer, as it is likely to get OP started on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (however, this is not quite that is you want exactly):

```
res = a1.group_by {|x| x[0] }.reduce({}) {|h, x| h[ x[0] ] = x[1].reduce({}) {|hh, xx| hh[ xx[2] ] = xx[3..-1] ; hh } ; h }
# => {"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12], "Regular Hours"=>["", 18]}, "Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14], "Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}}
```

the exact thing is doing with additional step:

```
res.keys.map {|k| {k => res[k]}}
# => [{"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12], "Regular Hours"=>["", 18]}}, {"Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14], "Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}}]
```

Comment: is it the best way @Malo

Answer (score 1):

```
a1.each_with_object({}) do |array, result|
  result[array[0]] ||= {}
  result[array[0]].merge!(array[2] => [array[3], array[4]])
end.map { |k, v| { k => v } }

# => [{"Akiyo Riggs"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 12], "Regular Hours"=>["", 18]}}, {"Bingo"=>{"OverTime Hours"=>["", 14], "Regular Hours"=>["", 32]}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |(name, _, hours_type, a, b), hash|
  hash[name] ||= {}
  hash[name][hours_type] = [a, b]
end.map do |name, values_hash|
  {name => values_hash}
end
```